# Does order of tag, id, class and attribute in CSS selector matter?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<input id="foo" class="bar" name="baz">
```

Are the following selectors equal (*or even valid*):

**CSS**

```
input#foo.bar[name=baz] { }
input.bar#foo[name=baz] { }
input[name=baz].bar#foo { }
/* etc */
```

And is it possible to move the element name to, say, end?

Edit: I know what specificity is, I want to know in which order the tag, id, class and attributes need to be specified.

Comment: If you have ID, so why need any other selectors? There may be only one unique ID.

Comment: Then what is the question? If they are valid is easy to find out: try it or read the specs. If they are equal should be obvious if you know specificity: they all reach the same level because they all have the same selectors.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference, because all have same specificity. Go through this link, you will have a clear idea about it. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all valid, as they comply with the syntax of [sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sequence). They are equivalent, since their meaning, including specificity, are defined in a manner that does not depend on the order of the components.

It is not possible to move the element name (type selector) to the end, for purely syntactic reasons. The spec says that a simple selector “always begins with a type selector or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence”. This is to be interpreted so that the type selector, *if present*, must appear first. This is natural since there would be no way to distinguish it from e.g. a preceding class selector (a space could not be used since it has a quite special meaning in CSS selector syntax: `.bar input` is a valid selector and means something quite different from `input.bar`).

Comment: This is absolutely correct, though you probably meant to say "does *not* depend on the order of the components".

Comment: 10 out of 10 for understanding the question (and for w3.org reference).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm so grateful I found your explanation; man the [Selector Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selector-syntax) has such a poor terminology to be honest. However the [Selector Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#syntax) does a much better job at explaining things.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer the answer of [@Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018372/1542290) as OP seemed to have changed the meaning of the question by minor edit, but if anyone's interested in specificity question before edit, than please read ahead.

---

First of all, neither of the selectors make sense, to be true, they are *over specific*.

Your selector holds an `id` which will be unique, so defining `class` as well as `attr=val` is not required
<sup>(If you are not using the same `id` for other element in some OTHER document..)</sup>

If for some case, you need them, say to override, like... *(makes sense)*

```
input#foo.bar[name=baz] {
   /* More specificity overrides the selector below */
}

input[name=baz] {
   /* Styles here */
}
```

*Are the following selectors equal* - **YES**, they are equal as far as the specficity goes, they all return a score of 121

[image]

<sup>[Credits](http://specificity.keegan.st/)</sup>

---

*(or even valid)* - **Completely Valid**

---

Does order of <s>tag</s><sup>(Not relevant)</sup>, `id`, `class` - **NO**, whatever the order of attributes are, it doesn't matter.

**BUT**

The *order of your CSS declaration block in the stylesheet matters*, the last selector will override common properties as all the three selectors have equal specificity.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjm5X/) *(All three will render green text, regardless of the order of their attributes, but if you shuffle the CSS selectors block, the last one will override the common properties of previous two selectors - unless you define `!important` in one of the selector properties)*

---

*And is it possible to move the element `name`<sup>(Attribute)</sup> to, say, end?* - **YES**

---

***<s>Pros</s> & Cons —***

- All the selectors are overspecific
- Bad as far as performance goes
- Using `attr=val` selector, you are assuming that the `value` of the `name` attribute won't change, if it does, you will have to change your selectors as well.

> P.S : Have an habit of quoting the attribute values.

Comment: Can I move `input` to the end e.g. `#foo.bar[name=baz]{what comes here}input`?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of "order" here. He's not asking about the order of CSS rules or the order of declarations, he's asking about the order of simple selectors within the compound selector. And from the number of upvotes it looks like a lot of others have misunderstood the question as well. (The question was just recently edited to clarify though.)

Comment: Also there are legitimate reasons to include other selectors besides an ID, for example if the element with that ID may or may not have a class and you want to make sure you only select it if it has that class. I think the example here is over-specific simply for academic reasons (asking about the order of 1) type 2) class 3) ID and 4) attribute selectors), rather than being a real selector in a real stylesheet.

Comment: @BoltClock Yea, wouldn't change though as Jukka already answered, and I had answered him in the comment as well, so as far as the answer goes, it was on topic before the edit was made, and thanks for explaining some basics as well :)

Comment: @BoltClock Also, he didn't specified the selector in the question, which he commented on my answer, else would've cleared out the fuzz at first place..

Answer (score 1):

Those are all legal:

```
<input type-"text" id="foo" class="bar" name="baz">

input#foo.bar[name=baz] { border:1px solid blue; }
input.bar#foo[name=baz] { border:1px solid red; }
input[name=baz].bar#foo { border:1px solid green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGj5B/

Remove the various style blocks and note that each selector will select the textbox.

By "equal", if you are asking is they have equivalent specificity, then the answer is yes given each selector has the same amount of elements, classes, attribute selectors, and ids. Since they are all equal, the order of the blocks in your stylesheet will serve to determine which conflicting styles will win out.

You cannot move the element to the end, as the other segments of the selector describe it by coming after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all of them are legal , But while execution the Later one Will over ride the Earlier Declarations,but some exceptions are there

check the Flow exceptions Here

```
input[name=baz].bar#foo { border:1px solid green; }
input.bar#foo[name=baz] { border:1px solid red; }
input#foo.bar[name=baz] { border:1px solid blue; }
input { border:1px solid #000000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGj5B/

for More Details Refer this Question..
[The sequence of execution of CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553425/the-sequence-of-execution-of-css)

Comment: No, you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ohh!! what i am Missing? @BoltClock