# Which css selector is targeted first? the ID or class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to know which of the id or class selectors takes precedence in an html tag when declaring it? And is there a specific way to declare them or does it matter at all?

EG.

```
<div class="class-name" id="id-name"></div> or <div id="id-name" class="class-name">
```

Comment: Use google search....

Comment: In term of specificity, ID has a higher value than any other selectors in CSS. No matter it is declared before or after other attributes of the element.

Comment: Thanks Hashem, That answers my question

Answer (score 0):

```
ID is always get priority in an html tag as well css
```

css

```
    #test1{ border:1px solid red;}

.test1{ border:1px solid red;}
#test2{ border:1px solid green;}

  .test2{ border:1px solid green;}
```

html

```
<div class="test1" id="test1">test1</div> or <div id="test2" class="test2">test2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't matter the order. But like @Rupesh say, `id` tag is the **first** to 'execute'. More info, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22014463/4489728).

Comment: No, the id tag is not the first to "execute". You're confusing specificity with the cascade.

Comment: Now I want to know more about it. What do you mean? :-/

Comment: I think the best way is to test this scenario by yourself to see the proof. I've done it and it is true that ID tags have higher precedence over the class selector.